# JPA Join criteria query with singular attribute

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

I have 2 entities like these:

```
EntityX:
id Long
name  String
entityYId  Long


EntityY (this entity is very hard, because it has a lot of data)
id Long
name String
xxx
xxx
.....
```

I need to do something like

```
Root<EntityX> xRoot = criteriaQuery.from(EntityX.class);
Join<EntityX, EntityY> yJoin = xRoot.join("entityYId", JoinType.LEFT);
```

I need yJoin because I need with JPA criteria this multiselect:

```
pId = xRoot.get("id");   
pName = xRoot.get("name");
pEntityYName = yJoin.get("name");

cr.multiselect(
    cb.construct(
      ResultData.class,
      pId,
      pName,
      pEntityYName));
```

Can I do it? If it not possible, what can I do to solve this, REMEMBER! I need only "entityYId" in EntityX not all entityY element.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the select method on Root class. See http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#SELECT_in_Criteria_Queries_ for more info

Comment: How can I get the name of my EntityY if in my EntityX I only have the entityYId reference not all the object?